# actual argument play.data.Form cannot be converted to play.api.data.Form

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

play doesn't convert my java form object to the scala world.

```
    [error] /home/myproject/split/frontend/app/controllers/frontend/Configuration.java:46: error: method render in class settings cannot be applied to given types;
    [error]             return ok(settings.render(settingsForm.fill(userSettings)));
    [error]                               ^
    [error]   required: play.api.data.Form<Settings>
    [error]   found: play.data.Form<Settings>
    [error]   reason: actual argument play.data.Form<Settings> cannot be converted to play.api.data.Form<Settings> by method invocation conversion
```

the view-template looks like this:

```
@(settingsForm: Form[Settings])

@import play.i18n._
@import helper._
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._

@main {

    @helper.form(action = controllers.frontend.routes.Configuration.setSettings) {
```

Any idea?

I should also mention that we use project split `main->frontend->common` and `main->backend->common`. We moved this page (view and controller) from `common` to `frontend`. It worked in `common` fine. Now in `frontend` I get this error.

I actually had a similar problem with a `java.util.List` and I had to add `templatesImport ++= Seq("java.util._", ...` to the settings:

```
  val frontend = play.Project(
      appName + "-frontend", appVersion, path = file("main/frontend")
  ).settings(
      templatesImport ++= Seq("java.util._", "models.frontend._")
  ).dependsOn(common).aggregate(common)
```

I tried with `play.data._` already, didn't help.

Comment: Maybe you should try to run `play clean` to your project and run it again?

Comment: did that, didn't help, thanks!

Comment: Have it been happen on every of your action method that pass `Form`? Sorry, I have no idea. I am using play 2.1.1, java 1.7, IntellijIDEA as code editor, and never faced such problem when passing `play.data.Form` to scala template (`play.data.api.Form`).

Comment: I should have mentioned that we have a project split, I'll edit my post..

Comment: opend an issue: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/issues/1114

Comment: Okay, if you know how to solve please answer this question, friend. So, the other who visited this site know.

Answer (score 1):

Your frontend project is a Scala project, not a Java project.  Add a dependency on javaCore to it, and it will be a Java project.  Then do a play clean compile, and everything should work.  Eg:

```
val frontend = play.Project(
  appName + "-frontend", appVersion, Seq(javaCore), path = file("main/frontend")
).settings(
  templatesImport ++= Seq("java.util._", "models.frontend._")
).dependsOn(common).aggregate(common)
```

Comment: It did solve the problem. Probably you could reproduce the issue with my dummy project which is available on this [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/443195/Play20issues1114.zip)